# iOS web/native app Facebook Login Popup - FAILS?

Tags: ios, facebook, web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to build a web app that will allow a user to login Facebook. Everything works in Firefox/Chrome/Safari (on the phone/tablet and on OSX).

When the App runs on the tablet (Native UIWebview and Web-app) it loads the first page perfectly.

When the user clicks the "connect with Facebook" button the app loads the Facebook logon page.

After the user logs in (again, in both a Native UIWebview and a web-app) the view turns white hanging on the URL: 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=[APP_ID]...' - this seems like it should not happen...

If I restart the app/web-app the user is logged in automatically, and redirected to the success page.

### What I think is causing the problem

When you run the web page in the Firefox/Chrome/Safari browsers the Facebook login Dialog pops up as a popup or another tab (the latter on the native Safari browser).

I believe that this is a problem with this popup page and how the Javascript communicates with itself when a successful login takes place. Something with `window.close` where there is no root page to return to (as the web-app and UIWebview only have one instance of the webview)... maybe?

### Failed work-around (UIWebview)

Since the app was hanging up on the previously mentioned URL I decided to add an if statement in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest(...)` to force the UIWebview to go to the success URL.

It loads the URL, but then before Facebook's Javascript SDK function `FB.getLoginStatus` function returns 'Connected' (It does return 'Connected' every time I've seen) The function `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout' function() {...});` is fired.

I don't understand why it is logging the user out, then telling me that the user is connected (logged in) - in that order.

**Any Ideas before I embark on trying to build this 100% native (and have to put up with apple's dev account and submitting the app)?**

### Login Script

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

        <script>
        var seccond_page = false;
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '[APP_ID]',
                status     : true,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                window.location.href = '<?= $success ?>';
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });

            FB.login(function(response) {
                alert(response.status);
                if (response.status) {
                    if (response.status == 'connected') {
                        window.location.href = '<?= $success ?>';
                    }
                }
            }, {scope: 'email, user_likes, user_status, user_birthday, user_location, publish_checkins'});

            $(document).on('click', '#fb_login_button', function() {
                FB.login();
            });
        };
        </script>
```

### Success Page

```
    <script>
        var fb_user_id = '';
        var fb_access_token = '';
        var user_location = '';
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '[APP_ID]',
                status     : true,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                oauth      : true
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                alert('Response - ' + response.status); 
                // the auth.logout is fired before the return of this in the failed fix
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        fb_user_id = response.authResponse.userID
                        fb_access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    }
                }

            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                alert('logout - auth.logout'); 
                // This event is fired before the above function in the failed fix
                window.location.href = '<?= site_url('fb_login'); ?>';
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response){
                if (response == '<?= $like_url ?>') {
                    //action
                }
            });
        };
</script>
```

All pages have the meta tag: `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

Comment: Show us your Facebook initialization and login code please.

Comment: This is happening because Facebook OAuth happens in a tabbed window as you rightly said and thus fails on a single window browser window like a UINativeWebView.

Comment: When you say 'Native UIWebview and Web-app' are you referring to a specific built-in or store app on the device, or something custom made? Also, when you say tablet, do you mean iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook calls auth.logout just before auth.login for reasons not clear to me. You should inspect the response parameter before assuming that the user really has been logged out. [Facebook docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) state:

> auth.logout - fired when the user logs out. The response object passed into the callback function looks like:
>      {
>        status: "",         /* Current status of the session */
>      }

If you execute your logout handling only if `response.status` is really `""`, you may find that during login, it calls `auth.login` listeners immediately after calling the `auth.logout` listener. Your current `auth.logout` handling prevents you from noticing this, because the page reload stops JS and ajax executions.